# Adding multiple instances of objects spritekit swift 3

Tags: swift, object, sprite-kit, multiple-instances, sknode

I am trying to add multiple instances of my object (bullet) so the player can shoot the bullet and then shoot another bullet. I am using the following code but it is giving me a thread 1 signal sigbart error. Can someone please explain whats wrong with the code? Thanks!

```
            let bulletmove = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.frame.height, duration: 2)

            let bulletremove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

            addChild(bullett)

            bullett.run(SKAction.sequence([bulletmove, bulletremove]))
```

Comment: also the bullet is an SKSpriteNode and is a color sprite, not an image

Comment: What does "bullett" refer to? Are you creating a new bullett object every time this code snippet runs?

Comment: You need to show the portion of your code where you create the bullet.

Comment: var bullet = SKSpriteNode()

Comment: and in my did move to view: bullett = self.childNode(withName: "bullett") as! SKSpriteNode

Comment: it seems to have to do with the "addChild(bullet)"

Comment: need more code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you add an SKSprite multiple times it would an error would occur.

What you need to do is create an SKSpritenode to add each time. You can have a function to do create bullets eachtime

```
func addBullet(){

var bullet = SKSpriteNode(imagenamed: "bullet")
bullet.position = //Give the point of origin as CGPoint. Maybe same as the shooter..
addChild(bullet)
bullet.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: self.frame.height, duration: 2))

}
```

So each time you call addBullet(),maybe in touches began , you can create new bullet that moves to end of screen without a crash. 
So main point is have var bullet = SKSpriteNode(imagenamed: "bullet") for each addChild.